# Ошибка после компиляции файлов python в exe (модуль pymorthy)

Tags: python, pymorphy2, auto-py-to-exe

Собрал парсер xlsx с целью проведения морфологического анализа фраз.

Для корректной работы морфологического анализатора **pymorphy2** установил python3.8.

***При запуске напрямую через Pycharm парсер и анализатор работает корректно.***

Но после компиляции в exe-файл, и запуске exe-шника, падаю с ошибкой:

> *"Can't find a dictionary for language 'ru'. Installed languages: [].*
> *Try installing pymorphy2-dicts-ru package."*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В виртуальном окружении модуль **pymorphy2-dicts-ru** установлен.

Компилирую exe-файл через **auto-py-to-exe**.

Пробовал ставить **pymorphy3** и дополнительно **pymorphy3-dicts-ru**:
ошибки после сборки в exe-файл не уходят.

---

**Компилирую ехе-файл командой:**

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import pymorphy3-dicts-ru main.py
```

**получаю ошибку:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "pymorphy3\analyzer.py", line 200, in __init__
  File "pymorphy3\analyzer.py", line 280, in choose_dictionary_path
  File "pymorphy3\analyzer.py", line 141, in lang_dict_path
ValueError: Can't find a dictionary for language 'ru'. Installed languages: []. Try installing pymorphy3-dicts-ru package.
[12080] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Разместите в вопросе какие ошибки пишет exe файл

Comment: Всё ясно, в pyinstaller параметром надо добавить словарь для RU (pymorphy3-dicts-ru).

Comment: Как Вы импортируете pymorphy3-dicts-ru в исходниках?

Comment: pip install pymorphy3-dicts-ru

Comment: Надо подключить файлы этого модуля при формировании ехе файла ну типо так --hidden-import modulename

Comment: Компилирую: "pyinstaller -F --hidden-import pymorphy3-dicts-ru main.py",
все равно падаю с ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049911/cannot-run-pyinstaller-executable-of-a-flask-server-valueerror-cant-find-a-di) есть возможное решение проблемы

вместо `--hidden-import` предлагается использовать `'--add-data '../site-packges/pymorhy2-dicts-ru/data'`

В самом коде программы перед импортом pymorphy2 необходимо вписать примерно следующее:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.environ["PYMORPHY2_DICT_PATH"] = str(pathlib.Path(sys._MEIPASS).joinpath('pymorphy2_dicts_ru/data'))
```

В файле `analyzer.py` также написано:

```
Alternatively (e.g. if you have your own precompiled dictionaries),
either create ``PYMORPHY2_DICT_PATH`` environment variable
with a path to dictionaries, or pass ``path`` argument
to :class:`pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer` constructor::

    >>> morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer(path='/path/to/dictionaries') # doctest: +SKIP
```